# Core data error when deleting a row

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a UITableViewController managing a grouped tableView. The tableView is populated from a fetchedResultsController.

If I click the Edit button in the NavigationBar, then select a row and click the Delete button, the row is deleted and all ends well.

However, if I swipe to reveal the Delete button in a row and click the Delete button, the app crashes with the following error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  ***
>   -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0] with userInfo (null) 2017-05-05 10:02:11.780
>   bibleapp[844:18560] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray
>   initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

I am using the code for this deletion is

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the managed object for the given index path
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Exception+was+caught+during+Core+Data+change+processing+NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification). You are likely to find an answer that helps.

Comment: The error occur when saving the context. I am searched this error but I don't get a suitable solution for this. Can you please tell me how to solve this error.?